# I am trying to move my character but instead of that the player wont move

Tags: python, pygame, resize, window, character

I am trying to move my character. I wrote it just like in a tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfWpgLFMI7w). It doesn't work. My character just wont move. I do not see any errors neither! Did I forget to add something to my code - in the `KEYDOWN` section? So the whole Code is here but the problem probably is in the `KEYDOWN` section or the player coordinates. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

pygame.display.set_caption("Baloon War!")
icon = pygame.image.load("Baloon war icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

centre_point = (WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2)

playerImg = pygame.image.load("RobiS.png")
playerX = 370
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0

def player(x,y):
    win.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

    def rescale(self):
        new_size = int(WINDOW_WIDTH * self.scale_factor)
        x, y = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original, (new_size, new_size))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

    def resize_button(self, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, x, y):
        self.width = WINDOW_WIDTH
        self.height = WINDOW_HEIGHT
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


def redrawMenuWindow():
    win.fill((0, 255, 110))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    redButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    cyanButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0, 150, 210))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 250, 110), (0, 450, 800, 250))
    win.blit(playerImg, (370, 400))


def redrawShopWindow():
    win.fill((200, 100, 30))

greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 275, 285, 250, 80, "Start")
redButton = button((255, 0, 0), 275, 475, 250, 80, "Quit")
cyanButton = button((20, 210, 180), 275, 380, 250, 80, "Shop")

game_state = "menu"
run = True
while run:
    if game_state == "menu":
        redrawMenuWindow()
    elif game_state == "game":
        redrawGameWindow()
    elif game_state == "shop":
        redrawShopWindow()
        pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            WINDOW_WIDTH = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)
            greenButton.resize_button(event.w*0.3, event.h*0.3, event.w/2, event.h/2)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")
                game_state = "game"
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if cyanButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 3button")
                game_state = "shop"


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)
            if cyanButton.isOver(pos):
                cyanButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                cyanButton.color = (20, 210, 180)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            playerX_change = -0.3
            print("Left arrow is pressed")
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 playerX_change = 0.3
                 print("Right arrow is pressed")
         if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                playerX_change = 0.1
                print("Keystroke has been released")

    pygame.display.update()

    playerX += playerX_change
    player(playerX, playerY)

pygame.display.update()
```

Please tell me the code . If you just tell me what the problem is, I maybe wouldn't know how to fix it. It would be best if you could tell me what's wrong and then write the correct code (not necessarily the whole code, just the part I need). If then the real problem is me because I forgot something or made a typo, then I am sorry for asking this question.

Comment: Can the player only move to the right? It looks like you are missing an if statement above `playerX_change = -0.3`. Something like `if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:`
It is possible you are moving the character left and right at the same time (-0.3 + 0.3 == 0.0)

Comment: Could you please explain which errors are you getting, and what you are trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: you have wrong indentations and you have `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` inside `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:`. So it checks `key` only when you move mouse but in this moment `event.type` can't be `KEYDOWN` because it is `MOUSEMOTION`. The same problem is with `KEYUP`. You have to use smaller indentations to move `KEYDOWN`/`KEYUP` outside `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:`

Comment: I now edited it. Maybe it's better explained and please answer and don't comment. And please rewrite the whole code right if you answer it.

Comment: don't expect that we will write all code for you.

Comment: BTW: you changed code - if it was mistake in your original code then describe it and don't change it because then our comments (and maybe answers) will not fit to your problem.

Comment: i just changed one thing. Can you read the whole code, try it yourself and then rewrite the code as an answer. Oh, and not all the code is really necesary. Just what I have to change???

Comment: you check `pygame.K_RIGHT` and change speed but you never check `pygame.K_LEFT` and not change speed. And in `KEYUP` you check `A`, `D` - so you have mess in code.

Comment: you have to draw all elements before `pygame.display.update()` but you display player after `pygame.display.update()`. Besizes you draw player two times - once in main loop and second time in `redrawGameWindow` - but this time always in the same place

Comment: Ok, well this is what I meant. I tried to fix the code but just ruined it. I didn't know what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is you draw `player` in main loop after `update()` so it updates image on monitor before you draw `player`. And finally it draws player before `fill()` which removes it from `Surface` and `update()` displays `Surface` without this `player` on monitor.

You draw second player in `redrawGameWindow` (before `update()` and this player is visible on screen but this player use `(370, 400)` so it never moves.

---

Full code with other changes.

Some of changes based on [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import pygame
#from pygame.locals import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred (but you don't even need it

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES) # PEP8

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE


# --- classes --- (CamerCaseNames) # PEP8

class Button():

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def is_over(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

    def rescale(self):
        new_size = int(WINDOW_WIDTH * self.scale_factor)
        x, y = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original, (new_size, new_size))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

    def resize_button(self, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, x, y):
        self.width = WINDOW_WIDTH
        self.height = WINDOW_HEIGHT
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names) # PEP8

def player(x,y):
    win.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def redraw_menu_window():
    win.fill((0, 255, 110))
    green_button.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    red_button.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    cyan_button.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

def redraw_game_window():
    win.fill((0, 150, 210))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 250, 110), (0, 450, 800, 250))
    win.blit(player_img, (player_x, player_y)) # use playerX, playerY

def redraw_shop_window():
    win.fill((200, 100, 30))

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

pygame.display.set_caption("Baloon War!")
icon = pygame.image.load("Baloon war icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#centre_point = (WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2)
center_point = win.get_rect().center 

player_img = pygame.image.load("RobiS.png")
player_x = 370
player_y = 500
player_x_change = 0

green_button = Button((0, 255, 0), 275, 285, 250, 80, "Start")
red_button = Button((255, 0, 0), 275, 475, 250, 80, "Quit")
cyan_button = Button((20, 210, 180), 275, 380, 250, 80, "Shop")

game_state = "menu"
run = True
while run:

    # --- draws ---

    if game_state == "menu":
        redraw_menu_window()
    elif game_state == "game":
        player_x += player_x_change
        redraw_game_window()
    elif game_state == "shop":
        redraw_shop_window()

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            WINDOW_WIDTH = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)
            greenButton.resize_button(event.w*0.3, event.h*0.3, event.w/2, event.h/2)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: # you can use `elif`
            if game_state == "menu":
                if green_button.is_over(pos):
                    print("clicked the button")
                    game_state = "game"
                if red_button.is_over(pos):
                    print("clicked the 2button")
                    run = False
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                if cyan_button.is_over(pos):
                    print("clicked the 3button")
                    game_state = "shop"
            elif game_state == "shop": # it has to be `elif` because in previous line is `game_state = "shop"` which could run it at once.
                game_state = "menu"

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION: # you can use `elif`
            if game_state == "menu":
                if green_button.is_over(pos):
                    green_button.color = (105, 105, 105)
                else:
                    green_button.color = (0, 255, 0)
                if red_button.is_over(pos):
                    red_button.color = (105, 105, 105)
                else:
                    red_button.color = (255, 0, 0)
                if cyan_button.is_over(pos):
                    cyan_button.color = (105, 105, 105)
                else:
                    cyan_button.color = (20, 210, 180)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # you can use `elif`
            if game_state == "game":
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    print("Left arrow is pressed")
                    player_x_change = -0.3
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player_x_change = 0.3
                    print("Right arrow is pressed")

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP: # you can use `elif`
            if game_state == "game":
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player_x_change = 0
                    print("Keystroke has been released")

# -- end ---
```

---

**BTW:** you shouls see `pygame.Rect()` which is used to keep position and size and it has `rect.right` which you can use instead of `x + width`. And it has funcitons to check collision and you can use it if mouse is over button.

---

**EDIT:** Code with more changes.

I use `pygame.Rect` to keep position and size, and to check collision in `Button`. I also created class `Player` and I check `events` inside classes `Button` and `Player`. Classes have also method `update()`, `draw()`, `handle_events` so you could keep them on list or `pygame.sprite.Group` and use `for`-loop to execute these functions for all objects.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES) # PEP8

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

# --- classes --- (CamerCaseNames) # PEP8

class Button():

    def __init__(self, color, hover_color, x, y, width, height, text='', outline=None, action=None):
        self.normal_color = color
        self.hover_color = hover_color

        self.color = self.normal_color

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.text = text

        self.rect_outline = self.rect.copy()
        self.rect_outline.x -= 2
        self.rect_outline.y -= 2
        self.rect_outline.width  += 4
        self.rect_outline.height += 4

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
        self.text_image = self.font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
        self.text_rect = self.text_image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

        self.outline = outline
        self.action = action

    def draw(self, win):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if self.outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, self.outline, self.rect_outline, 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect, 0)

        if self.text != '':
            win.blit(self.text_image, self.text_rect)

    def is_over(self, pos):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(pos)

    def rescale(self):
        new_size = int(WINDOW_WIDTH * self.scale_factor)
        x, y = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original, (new_size, new_size))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))

    def resize_button(self, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, x, y):
        self.rect.width = WINDOW_WIDTH
        self.rect.height = WINDOW_HEIGHT
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                if self.action:
                    self.action() # execute callback fuction
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if self.is_over(event.pos):
                self.color = self.hover_color
            else:
                self.color = self.normal_color


class Player():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        #self.image = pygame.image.load("RobiS.png")
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Obrazy/images/square-1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)
        self.player_x_change = 0
        # you need because you use float values to move player but `self.rect` can keep only int values
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x_change = 0

    def draw(self, win):
        self.rect.x = int(self.x)
        self.rect.y = int(self.y)
        win.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.x_change

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # you can use `elif`
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("Left arrow is pressed")
                self.x_change = -0.3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.x_change = 0.3
                print("Right arrow is pressed")

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP: # you can use `elif`
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.x_change = 0
                print("Keystroke has been released")

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names) # PEP8

def redraw_menu_window():
    win.fill((0, 255, 110))
    green_button.draw(win)
    red_button.draw(win)
    cyan_button.draw(win)

def redraw_game_window():
    win.fill((0, 150, 210))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 250, 110), (0, 450, 800, 250))
    player.draw(win)
    back_to_menu_button.draw(win)

def redraw_shop_window():
    win.fill((200, 100, 30))
    back_to_menu_button.draw(win)

def callback_green_button():
    global game_state

    print("clicked the button")
    game_state = "game"

def callback_red_button():
    global run

    print("clicked the 2button")
    run = False

def callback_cyan_button():
    global game_state

    print("clicked the 3button")
    game_state = "shop"

def callback_back_button():
    global game_state

    print("back button")
    game_state = "menu"

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

pygame.display.set_caption("Baloon War!")
#icon = pygame.image.load("Baloon war icon.png")
icon = pygame.image.load("Obrazy/images/ball.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

#centre_point = (WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2)
center_point = win.get_rect().center 

player = Player(370, 500)

green_button = Button((0, 255, 0), (105, 105, 105), 275, 285, 250, 80, "Start", (0, 0, 0), callback_green_button)
red_button = Button((255, 0, 0), (105, 105, 105), 275, 475, 250, 80, "Quit", (0, 0, 0), callback_red_button)
cyan_button = Button((20, 210, 180), (105, 105, 105), 275, 380, 250, 80, "Shop", (0, 0, 0), callback_cyan_button)

back_to_menu_button = Button((20, 210, 180), (105, 105, 105), 275, 380, 250, 80, "BACK", (0, 0, 0), callback_back_button)

game_state = "menu"
run = True
while run:

    # --- draws ---

    if game_state == "menu":
        redraw_menu_window()
    elif game_state == "game":
        redraw_game_window()
    elif game_state == "shop":
        redraw_shop_window()

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            WINDOW_WIDTH = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)
            green_button.resize_button(event.w*0.3, event.h*0.3, event.w/2, event.h/2)

        if game_state == "menu":
            green_button.handle_event(event)
            red_button.handle_event(event)
            cyan_button.handle_event(event)
        elif game_state == "game":
            player.handle_event(event)
            back_to_menu_button.handle_event(event)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    game_state = "menu"
        elif game_state == "shop":
            back_to_menu_button.handle_event(event)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    game_state = "menu"

    # --- updates ---

    if game_state == "menu":
        #green_button.update()
        #red_button.update()
        #cyan_button.update()
        pass
    elif game_state == "game":
        player.update()
    elif game_state == "shop":
        pass

# -- end ---
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem was that I forgot to add +0.3 or -0.3 in the `KEYDOWN` section. Thank you very much for showing me that and I appreciate that you took your time to answer me the question very good and write the WHOLE CODE :). So it was my fault for forgetting something in the code